# API authentication for Azure AD B2C users?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a back-end API available to programatically authenticate the external user against the Azure AD B2C instance by passing in the user credentials from within a MVC web application (without showing the login page) as we do from a Native Client like console application?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication through a back-api that accepts user credentials is achieved through the OAuth Resource Owner Password Grant.

**Azure AD B2C does not support the "Resource Owner Password Grant" yet.**

You can support this feature ask and get updates on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential).